# Five bhavas as explained by Sri Ramakrishna

Tags: puranas, tantra, ramakrishna

The concepts of 'bhava' is different in the Tantras and the Puranas. Sri Chaitanya mentions five bhavas to worship Sri Krishna, each corresponding to a particular relation with God -Santa, Dasya, Sakhya, Vatsalya and Madhura, of which, Madhura is the highest form. (As per Sri Chaitanyacharitamrita,it was Ray Ramananda who mentioned these five bhavas to Mahaprabhu).

In tantra, bhava means the state of wisdom. There are three bhavas-Pashu, Veera and Divya.

Sri Ramakrishna got siddhi in all the five bhavas mentioned by Mahaprabhu as recorded in Sri Sri Ramakrishnaleelaprasanga.
Besides these,in His Kathamrita, He mentions five bhavas to worship Bhagavati : Veera, Dasi, Sakhi, Bhagni and Santana, each corresponding to a particular relation with the Goddess, santana bhava being the best. He says that He used all of these except the veera bhava.

Is there any scriptural evidence of these last five or are these Sri Ramakrishna's own innovations or contributions?

Comment: Chaitanya Mahaprabhu expounded Vaishnava school of Bhakti that prevailed and influenced Sri Ramakrishna as well. ( Not specifically pinged messages apply directly to  sender.placed above ).

Comment: @Narasimham Right! So my comment (which is not what the main question is asking) is naturally the right one to ponder through merely because one can simply answer this main question by saying that *No, it is not his innovation, Ramakrishna got these ideas from Chaitanya!*  (FYI I didn't receive any notification of your last comment so I think pinging sender placed above may not work)